# keeping around a child context across view controllers

Tags: ios, core-data

I looked around for how people might do add vs edit with core data.  I came across the WWDC 2012 - 214 video as well as this post: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ that talks about using a child context with the parent.  My question is, what if I need to create a temp object on one ViewController, and then pass that temp object a couple viewController's deep until I decide if I want to save or not.  Do I need to then pass the tempContext with me through the viewControllers?  Or do I just need to pass the NSManagedObject to the other viewControllers and it does not matter that the tempContext was a local variable to a method.  For example:

ViewController 1 does:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Route *route; // NSManagedObject subclass
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *mainMoc;
- (void)calculateRoute {
NSMangedObjectContext *temporaryContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
temporaryContext.parentContext = self.mainMOC;
  // calculate the route to possibly save at least one viewController deep
  self.route = route;

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
UIViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowDistanceViewController"]) {

    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)]) {
        [destination setValue:self.managedObjectContext forKey:@"managedObjectContext"];
    }
    if ([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(setRoute:)]) {
        [destination setValue:self.route forKey:@"route"];
    }
 }
```

Now in the destinationViewController, how do I throw away the object and/ or save it at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the object. You can access the context (regardless if child or main) from the object with

```
object.managedObjectContext
```

Comment: So it doesn't matter that the context goes away and is only local to that method where the object gets created?  I can still pass the object and still have access to the temp context even if it's not an ivar or something?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As stated, you can get the context from the object.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to be the case.  Once the tempContext loses scope, even though I have the NSManagedObject, the managedObjectContext property is null.

Comment: If your context is out of scope, how can the object not be? This might call for reviewing your application logic. If the scope of your context ends, you should not interact with its objects any more. You should have a valid context when dealing with managed objects: e.g. by getting it from the app delegate and fetching your object.